# Illegal response header Scala Spray pipelining

Tags: scala, spray, spray-client

I'm getting the follow error when I am trying to pipeline a request from Scala spray

```
[play-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-14] INFO application - Pipelining chain request
[WARN] [03/19/2015 11:08:49.115] [application-akka.actor.default-dispatcher-2] [akka://application/user/IO-HTTP/group-0/0] Illegal response header: Illegal 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header: Unexpected end of input, expected $timesAccess$minusControl$minusAllow$minusOrigin (line 1, pos 1):

^
```

and here is where I am building the request:

```
val pipeline =
  addCredentials(BasicHttpCredentials("API_KEY",
    "API_SECRET")) ~>  sendReceive

val response: Future[HttpResponse] = pipeline(Post(api,notification))
Logger.info("Pipelining chain request")
response
```

I don't really know much about `Access Control Allow Origin`. Do I need to add some sort of header to this request to get it to work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error itself means [`Access-Control-Allow-Origin`](http://www.w3.org/TR/cors/#access-control-allow-origin-response-header) header wasn't parsed correctly (see [grammar](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-http/src/main/scala/spray/http/parser/CORSHeaders.scala)). This header is pretty new and allows [Cross Origin Resource Sharing](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cross-origin_resource_sharing). Examples of normal `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`(from [here](https://github.com/spray/spray/blob/master/spray-http/src/test/scala/spray/http/HttpHeaderSpec.scala)):

```
"Access-Control-Allow-Origin" in {
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *" =!= `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`(AllOrigins)
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: null" =!= `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`(SomeOrigins(Nil))
  "Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://spray.io" =!= `Access-Control-Allow-Origin`(SomeOrigins(Seq("http://spray.io")))
}
```

I can guess that you may use some old version of spray, which doesn't support multiple origins or maybe it's related to [this](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/spray-user/qa-LJjHID4Y). Anyway, server returns a response with this header only if `Origin` header is specified in request (which means CORS initiation), so the problem should be solved by removing `Origin` header from it.

UPDATE: This is a bug of chain.com API, you use. If `Origin` header is not specified, they return `Access-Control-Allow-Origin:` (empty string) to you, so it's not parsable:

> ```
> > curl -v https://api.chain.com/v2/notifications -X POST
> > POST /v2/notifications HTTP/1.1
> > User-Agent: curl/7.41.0
> > Host: api.chain.com
> > Accept: */*
> >
> < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
> < Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
> < Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PATCH,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS,HEAD
> < Access-Control-Allow-Origin:
> < Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
> < Date: Sun, 22 Mar 2015 01:38:07 GMT
> < Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=25920000; includeSubDomains
> < Vary: Accept-Encoding
> < Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="chain-api"
> < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> < X-Frame-Options: DENY
> < X-Xss-Protection: 1
> < Content-Length: 47
> < Connection: keep-alive
> <
> {"code":"CH004","message":"Must authenticate"}
> ```

You have to specify some `Origin` as workaround:

> ```
> >curl -v https://api.chain.com/v2/notifications -X POST -H "Origin: http://google.com"
> > POST /v2/notifications HTTP/1.1
> > User-Agent: curl/7.41.0
> > Host: api.chain.com
> > Accept: */*
> > Origin: http://google.com
>
> < HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
> < Access-Control-Allow-Credentials: true
> < Access-Control-Allow-Methods: GET,POST,PATCH,PUT,DELETE,OPTIONS,HEAD
> < Access-Control-Allow-Origin: http://google.com
> < Content-Type: text/plain; charset=utf-8
> < Date: Sun, 22 Mar 2015 01:39:10 GMT
> < Strict-Transport-Security: max-age=25920000; includeSubDomains
> < Vary: Accept-Encoding
> < Www-Authenticate: Basic realm="chain-api"
> < X-Content-Type-Options: nosniff
> < X-Frame-Options: DENY
> < X-Xss-Protection: 1
> < Content-Length: 47
> < Connection: keep-alive
> ```

Comment: Here is the api that I am trying to call https://chain.com/docs#notifications-create

Comment: it's a bug of `chain.com` API - they send you `Access-Control-Allow-Origin` with value "" (empty string, not-parsable) rif no `Origin` header specified, the possible workaround is to actually specify this `Origin` header.

Comment: What would I populate the origin header with? Would I populate this when handling the response or sending the request?

Comment: when sending the request (I've added the example). You may use any valid URI (like `htttp://example.com`) - it doesn't matter as it's a workaround.

Comment: So in my example I would have something like `addHeader("Origin", "mydomain.com")`

Comment: Sorry, I can't award the bounty for another 16 hours. I'll give it to you when the time lock expires.